# Where can I find the database Room.DataBaseBuilder(...).build() creates?

Tags: android-room

I'm quite new to android and I am currently working on a app which should utilize a Room database. Following the documentation a room database can be created through the following lines:

```
        myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, MyDatabase.class, "MyDB")
            .build();
```

Now where did room create the database file?
It can't be found in my project folder.

The documentation doesn't mention anything about it and -generally speaking- barely gives any information about how this thing works.

Where is the database?
Does DatabaseBuilder.build() manage, to open the existing database created from previous app launches?

The list of questions is long.

Any information about the .build() thing aswell as further information about Room (misconceptions etc.) are very appreciated, for the documentation doesn't really make things clear for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Now where did room create the database file?

The database (a file) will be placed at the default location on the actual device which is data/data/<the_package_name>/database/MyDB.

In your case, as you have coded :-

```
myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, MyDatabase.class, "MyDB")
    .build();
```

Then the database files will be: -

```
 data/data/<your_package_name>/databases/MyDB
 data/data/<your_package_name>/databases/MyDB-wal
 data/data/<your_package_name>/databases/MyDB-shm
```

> It can't be found in my project folder.
> The database file is not part of the project, it is a file that is created and maintained on the actual device on which the App has been installed.

**However**, you can use Database Inspector (now App Inspection) on Android Studio to view the database e.g. :-

[image]

You can also view the files, if whatever device you test on allows access, by using Device File Explorer. e.g.

[image]

> Does DatabaseBuilder.build() manage, to open the existing database created from previous app launches?

Yes, if the file exists then it is opened  otherwise the file is created. If you uninstall the App this effectively delete's the file. The whole idea of a database is that it persists.

The `build()` undertakes various tasks, primarily seeing if the underlying file exists and then opening the file. In doing so it

1. extracts the version number that is stored in the file and compares the number against the number coded within the App (via the @Database).

- If the version number from the App is greater then an attempt is tried to find a Migration (recently AutoMigration's have been added to Room).

2. compares the expected schema (according to the entities defined as part of the @Database), against what is found in the file.

- A mismatch will result in the app crashing, so fixes would have to be made.

**Note** references to file is a simplification, by default Room uses a loggin mode called WAL (Write-Ahead Logging). In WAL mode there will be an additional 2 files that the SQLite routines maintain (you don't need to do anything):-

1. the database file name suffixed with -wal is the primary wal file into which changes are written (they are applied to the main database automatically).
2. the database file name suffixed with -shm (this is a WAL file for the WAL file).

Comment: Just noticed that I didn't answer. Your explanation is gold! Didn't know about the database inspector either.